# Android MQTT Application

Tags: android, mqtt

My team is building an Android application which uses MQTT (Mosquito) to connect to a PCBs. We are seeing an issue where once a day (Sometimes more) it'll disconnect and we have to reboot the computer for it to reconnect. Haven't been able to pinpoint the issue but are able to see logs. Any thoughts on this?

```
2022-03-29 08:11:24.442 1327 1382 W BroadcastQueue: Timeout of broadcast BroadcastRecord{22a1d6f u0 MqttService.pingSender.paho27313692436} - receiver=android.os.BinderProxy@991d308, started 60001ms ago 
2022-03-29 08:11:24.443 1327 1382 W BroadcastQueue: Receiver during timeout of BroadcastRecord{22a1d6f u0 MqttService.pingSender.paho27313692436} : BroadcastFilter{4ae74c6 10157/u0 ReceiverList{1937aa1 3293 com.example.deadbolt_frontend/10157/u0 remote:991d308}}
```

Shortly after it disconnects

```
2022-03-29 08:14:14.641 3293 3293 I MqttClientImp: Attempting MQTT connection
2022-03-29 08:14:14.643 1327 6371 I am_uid_active: 10054 
2022-03-29 08:14:14.845 3293 20643 I payment : \*\*\* permitsImpl keysize: 2048 
2022-03-29 08:14:14.845 3293 20644 I payment : \*\*\* permitsImpl keysize: 2048 
2022-03-29 08:14:14.846 3293 20643 I payment : getPCIFlag failed. 
2022-03-29 08:14:14.846 3293 20644 I payment : getPCIFlag failed. 
2022-03-29 08:14:14.846 3293 20643 I payment : RSA minSize: 1024 
2022-03-29 08:14:14.846 3293 20644 I payment : RSA minSize: 1024
```

We tried completing a silent reconnect to no avail.

Comment: None of those log entries are really helpful, but if you have to reboot the machine with the broker on it to fix things, why are you looking on the phone and not at the mosquitto broker logs on that machine (before you reboot it)?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.